# Replace values in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, tensor-indexing

There are those two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([
    [
        [1,2,3,0,0],
        [4,5,6,0,0],
        [7,8,9,0,0]
    ],
    [
        [1,3,5,0,0],
        [2,4,6,0,0],
        [1,1,1,0,0]
    ]
])

b = np.array([
    [
        [1,2],
        [2,3],
        [3,4]
    ],
    [
        [4,1],
        [5,2],
        [6,3]
    ]
])
```

with shapes:

`"a" shape: (2, 3, 5), "b" shape: (2, 3, 2)`

I want to replace the last two elements from array `a` with those from array `b`, e.g.

```
c = np.array([
    [
        [1,2,3,1,2],
        [4,5,6,2,3],
        [7,8,9,3,4]
    ],
    [
        [1,3,5,4,1],
        [2,4,6,5,2],
        [1,1,1,6,3]
    ]
])
```

However, `np.hstack((a[:,:,:-2], b))` throws a Value Error:

> all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must
>   match exactly

and in general doesn't look like it's the correct function to use. Append doesn't work either.

Is there a method in numpy that can do that or do I need to iterate over the arrays with a for loop and manipulate them manually?

Comment: `a[:, :, -2:] = b`

Comment: Or simply use the ellipsis notation, `a[..., -2:] = b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Non-overwriting* method:

- `a[:,:,-2:]` fetches the zeros at the end; use `a[:,:,:3]`.
- According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), `np.hstack(x)` is equivalent to `np.concatenate(x, axis=1)`. Since you want to join the matrices on their innermost rows, you should use `axis=2`.

Code:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a[:,:,:3], b), axis=2)
array([[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        [4, 5, 6, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9, 3, 4]],

       [[1, 3, 5, 4, 1],
        [2, 4, 6, 5, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 6, 3]]])
```

Comment: ah it's the second axis!! I was trying with 0 and 1 :facepalm:

Answer (score 3):

You could use the direct indices like so:

```py
a[:, :, 3:] = b
```